# Does we have something to check whether data is available in UART port in embedded linux..?

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, uart

Is it possible to check from user space application, whether data is available for reading in the UART port. The code is written in C over Embedded Linux Platform.

For Example :

```
while(isDataAvalable(fileDescriptor)) {
    read(fileDescriptor, buffer, 10)
}
```

I am looking for some function provided by linux, **which returns true if there is  data to be read from port and false if there is no data**. But the function itself **should not remove the data from hardware buffer**, until the data is  read using "**read**" method.

If there is no such inbuilt function in linux, is there a way to create a wrapper  function using the linux system calls to achieve the above functionality, which can be used by the user space application..?

Comment: Have you tried using [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)?

Comment: Your understanding of I/O and how the serial port works is flawed. The device driver always reads the UART port as soon as possible to prevent a receive ***overrun error***. The data is stored in a system buffer. (Actually there may be a series of buffers, e.g. for the line discipline.) The userspace **read()** always retrieves data from a buffer, never directly from hardware. See http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#5_1_3

Comment: I agree with your point that the user-space **read** call retrieves data from a buffer. What I need is a function to check whether any data is available in that buffer. **read()** always take the data from the buffer, I dont want to take the data, just need to see if there is some data in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using poll() in linux.

poll() shall be able to tell whether there is data to read and is very useful in such scenarios. It monitors a set of file descriptors and waits for one of the file descriptor to become ready to perform I/O.

poll() checks whether any desired event(like arrival of data) has occurred. If the requested event has occurred, it shall alert via POLLIN that the event has happened(*there is data to read*) in the particular file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use Qt framework, than the QSerialPort is emitting signal QIODevice::readyRead() when data is available. (you could deploy Qt without gui for your platform to minimize the footprint)